# File Iteration Returns No Data in files

Tags: python, csv

My Script below is supposed to iterate through files located in this folder, with the ending csv. It reaches each file, but deletes all the data, instead of turning the 'NA' to 0.

```
import csv
import os
import sys 

#file location
folderpath = (r'\\Deturbansci19\cvi2$\ClientServices\CC&A\Current\SSO\BRD Work\Parts Opportunity\Sample data')
#print (folderpath)

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(folderpath, topdown = False):
    for name in files:
        if 'Archive' not in root and name.endswith ('.csv'):
            f = os.path.join(r'\\Deturbansci19\cvi2$\ClientServices\CC&A\Current\SSO\BRD Work\Parts Opportunity\Sample data\\'+name)
            #print (os.path.join(root, name))
            newfile = (r'\\Deturbansci19\cvi2$\ClientServices\CC&A\Current\SSO\BRD Work\Parts Opportunity\Sample data\\'+name)
            with open(f, 'rb') as csvfile, open(newfile,'w',newline='') as newcsvfile:
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
                csv_writer = csv.writer(newcsvfile, delimiter=',')

                for lines in csv_reader:
                    #Replacing lines
                    replaced = lines[7].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[7] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[8].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[8] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[17].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[17] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[18].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[18] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[19].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[19] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[20].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[20] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[21].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[21] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[22].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[22] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[23].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[23] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[24].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[24] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[25].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[25] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[26].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[26] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[27].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[27] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[28].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[28] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[29].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[29] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[30].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[30] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[31].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[31] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[32].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[32] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[33].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[33] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[34].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[34] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[35].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[35] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[36].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[36] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[37].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[37] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[38].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[38] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[39].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[39] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[40].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[40] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[41].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[41] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[42].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[42] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[43].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[43] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[44].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[44] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[45].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[45] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[46].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[46] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[47].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[47] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[48].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[48] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[49].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[49] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[50].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[50] = replaced
                    replaced = lines[51].replace('NA', '0')
                    lines[51] = replaced
                   #Testing Purposes
                   #print (replaced)
                   #replaced = lines[0:50].replace('NA', '0')
                   #lines[0:50] = replaced
                   csv_writer.writerow(lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `f` and `newfile` are the same path. So in your `with` statement, you're opening one file for reading, and then opening the same file for writing. Opening the file for writing deletes the file.